# Multiwii drone not functioning properly

Tags: quadcopters, multirotor, arduino-drone

I have used 1800kv motors, Arduino Uno, and Flysky FSI6 transmitter and reciever.

This is the code I used for the config.h file:

```
   #define QUADX
 #define MINTHROTTLE 1150 // (*) (**)

  /****************************    Motor maxthrottle    *******************************/
    /* this is the maximum value for the ESCs at full power, this value can be increased up to 2000 */
    #define MAXTHROTTLE 1850

  /****************************    Mincommand          *******************************/
    /* this is the value for the ESCs when they are not armed
       in some cases, this value must be lowered down to 900 for some specific ESCs, otherwise they failed to initiate */
    #define MINCOMMAND  1000

  /**********************************  I2C speed for old WMP config (useless config for other sensors)  *************/
    #define I2C_SPEED 100000L    // //100kHz normal mode, this value must be used for a genuine WMP
    // #define I2C_SPEED 400000L   //400kHz fast mode, it works only with some WMP clones

  /***************************    Internal i2c Pullups   ********************************/
    /* enable internal I2C pull ups (in most cases it is better to use external pullups) */
    //#define INTERNAL_I2C_PULLUPS

  /**********************************  constant loop time  ******************************/
    #define LOOP_TIME 2800
      #define GY_521
```

The rest of the code is the same as multiwi's config.h.

I tried adjusting the pid values but the motors are not running at a stable speed and are making the drone crash before it takes off.